# Jenkins Cloudformation plugin gives InValid Client Id error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to launch a cloudformation stack via the jenkins-cloudformation plugin  from a template stored in git but I receive an error "Invalid Client Id" even though I give proper access_key and secret_key.

Besides, an appropriate IAM role is attached to the ec2 instance on which jenkins is running and the instance metadata is accessible to jenkins user.

And this error comes up irrespective of whether I pass secretKey, accessKey in jenkins configuration or not.

Can someone please guide me where it's going wrong.

[image: Jenkins config]

Error

```
Building in workspace /apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Cloudformation_Test
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://xxxx.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://xxxx.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Gitlab user webadmdeamon to perform CICD with Jenkins
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress https://xxx.get +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 827b91075eb0ae5901b641a7588b9b5769ad2ce7 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 827b91075eb0ae5901b641a7588b9b5769ad2ce7
Commit message: "Add new file"
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk 827b91075eb0ae5901b641a7588b9b5769ad2ce7 # timeout=10
Determining to create or update Cloud Formation stack: JenkinsCloudformationTest
Stack not found: JenkinsCloudformationTest. Reason: Detailed Message: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: be71618c-3027-11e9-8d00-45421bf87ce0)
Status Code: 403
Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId

Creating Cloud Formation stack: JenkinsCloudformationTest
Failed to create stack: JenkinsCloudformationTest. Reason: Detailed Message: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: be73364d-3027-11e9-8d00-45421bf87ce0)
Status Code: 403
Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId

Finished: FAILURE
```

EDIT---

I am able to create a stack using aws cli in the same ec2 instance and with the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log shows that your issue is authentication-related:

```
Reason: Detailed Message: The security token included in the request is invalid.
(Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request 
ID: be71618c-3027-11e9-8d00-45421bf87ce0)
Status Code: 403
Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId
```

The problem could be either a bug in the Jenkins plugin or (more likely) a problem with the keys you are providing to the plugin.

The source code for the plugin ([code ref](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-cloudformation-plugin/blob/e73c32654a8293a8541ce63fb4a9ea1f23c040d1/src/main/java/com/syncapse/jenkinsci/plugins/awscloudformationwrapper/CloudFormation.java#L255-L256)), meanwhile, appears to indicate that the plugin always tries to use the access keys you provide. If you leave the key fields blank I guess it tries empty strings as the keys. Thus, the IAM role attached to the instance is probably not relevant.

Note that the error you receive `InvalidClientTokenId` is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html):

> **InvalidClientTokenId**
>
> The X.509 certificate or AWS access key ID provided does not exist in our records.
>
> HTTP Status Code: 403

Now, you mention in your update that:

> I am able to create a stack using aws cli in the same ec2 instance and with the same user.

So firstly, try that again, and then have a look in [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/). Filter by EventName=CreateStack, and then you'll see something like this:

[image]

Is it really the same user and Access Key?

I suspect you're going to find that it isn't, and the fix for you will be to provide correct Access Keys. If not, let me know and we can consider other possibilities.

Comment: Yw. Did you find the root cause?

Comment: Indeed the issue was related to IAM user. I was trying to use IAM role instead which was not working.